# Debug a Python C++ extension from Eclipse (under Linux)

Tags: c++, python, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project that is called in Python (via boost-python) and I want to debug the C++ code from python process. How can I do that? In Windows with Visual Studio I can use the functionality `attach to process`. How to achieve the same in Eclipse?
Thanks

Comment: it's not really about Eclipse, you should refer to the CDT project for this kind of thing.

Comment: You can try with http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: No, the project runs on Linux

Answer (score 0):

For me it works great just adding a debug configuration in C/C++ for the program /usr/bin/python (or whatever search path you have to the python interpreter) and then put the python program you want to run as the arguments. Put the breakpoints you want in the C-code and you should be all set for running the debug configuration and opening the debug perspective.

If it still does not work you may also check that you are using Legacy (or Standard) Process Launcher. For some reason the GDB process launcher does not seem to work here.